# Relation data-rate and bit-rate of ADC

Tags: adc, sampling, conversion, bit-rate, oversampling

I came accross the folowing question, where the accepted answer contains a formula showing the relation between bit-rate and data-rate for a delta sigma ADC. My question is, why that relation is valid. There is nothing stated regarding clock rate of the ADC in its datasheet. Why is this relation posted in the accepted answer valid? Does that count for all delta sigma ADCs?
Maybe this is a stupid question with an obvious answer, but would really appreciate an answer to make this more clear. A link to an app-note/datasheet containing this formula/explanation is appreciated as well.

Formula:

**data_rate = f_clk / 2^(bit)**

[Question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13737/confusion-with-adc-conversion-in-mcp3424?answertab=active#tab-top)

[Datahseet of ADC](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/22088b.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is not exact but should help to provide at least a good intuition.*

In a word the answer is "decimation".

As explained in [this Maxim tutorial](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1870) and other places, the front end of a delta-sigma ADC yields a 1-bit data stream:

> The output of the sigma-delta modulator is a 1-bit data stream at the sampling rate, which can be in the megahertz range. The purpose of the digital-and-decimation filter [...] is to extract information from this data stream and reduce the data rate to a more useful value. [...]

When you [decimate](https://dspguru.com/dsp/faqs/multirate/decimation/) a sampled signal, you in general gain one extra bit of resolution each time you halve the frequency. So a set of 1-bit samples at \$f_{s0}\$ could also be represented as a set of 2-bit samples at \$f_{s0}/2\$, or a set of 3-bit samples at \$f_{s0}/4\$, and so forth.

So for \$n\$-bit data we'd need to halve the frequency \$n-1\$ times, which is not quite the formula you have above -- we're missing one factor of two. I dunno, maybe the delta-sigma modulator is already sampling at \$f_{clk}/2\$?

BTW your datasheet might not mention \$f_{clk}\$ explicitly, but the table on page 15 shows quite neatly how each time we add 2 extra bits to the resolution we cut the sample rate by a factor of 4. (Note that the "data rate" in that table is *samples* per second, not *bits* per second.)

Comment: thanks for your input. That is the stuff I already knew more or less. But it really bothers me that I do not understand where this formula comes from (it seems to be right) or when it is valid, for what kind of ADCs. Still hope someone can solve this mystery :)

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question, because to my eyes it's all there. For a "normal" ADC (for example a SAR) the data rate is simply (samples/sec) * (bits/sample). For a sigma-delta the data rate is the raw 1-bit sample rate (which is typically f_clk), divided by the decimation (which is 2^(number of octaves), which is the same thing as 2^(number of bits)). That's where the formula comes from, and that was (I thought) is laid out above. What else is missing?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how would I determine  f_clk if this is not mentioned in the provided datasheet? Just calculate it with: data_rate(in sps)*2^(number of bits)?

Comment: Yeah strange, based on my cursory read it looks like they never specify f_clk. I guess because a casual user shouldn't care. Your formula would work. Or just extrapolate from Table 4-3: 240 SPS @ 12 bits... keep doubling the sample rate as we drop a bit, to get up to 491.52kHz f_clk. I think.

Comment: I also wonder because in the accepted answer here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13737/confusion-with-adc-conversion-in-mcp3424?answertab=active#tab-top  it seems pretty obvious to the user that f_clk is 983040 for the same ADC...

Comment: I repeat from my post above: "[...] we're missing one factor of two. I dunno, maybe the delta-sigma modulator is already sampling at f_clk/2?" ;-)

Comment: "maybe" ;) is there a clear indication in the datasheet that this is the case, im overlooking?

Comment: btw, in your second comment you mentioned f_clk=491.52kHz. What calculation did you exactly do to get to that value?

Comment: The same calculation I had mentioned before; just double the sample rate every time you drop a bit. Per Page 15 of the datasheet, you have 60 SPS at 14 bits and 240 SPS at 12 bits -- drop two bits, sample rate quadruples. To get to the 1-bit rate, just double it 11 more times: 240 * 2^11 = 491520.

Comment: thank you very much. The missing factor of two just keeps bothering me as I can not find anything on that in the datasheet ...